# How to override Accent color and Default background color windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to change the Accent color in my whole application to a custom color.
Currently it's coming whatever is selected in "Settings"
Also need to change the default background color for pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in `App.xml.cs` constructor

```
//This will change the default accent color
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Green;

//This will change the default background color for pages
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;

//other code
```

Similarly you can change the other Brush/Color specified in [**Theme resources for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)